# How can I get Number of Items of the Quantity field and calculate the TotalTax()?

Tags: java, eclipse, computer-science

> The toString() method will return a String that includes all of the items in the purchases array, organized by category.  toString() will also include the total cost of the order before taxes, the tax amount, the total amount (before tax + tax) and the number of items ordered.  The number of items ordered is determined by the quantity field and is not the same as the number of items stored in the purchases array (numPurchases).
> Here is my code:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Receipt {
private Item[] purchases;
private int numPurchases;

public Receipt(int capacity) {
    purchases = new Item[capacity];
    numPurchases = 0;
}

public void add(Item itm) {
        purchases[numPurchases] = itm;
        numPurchases++;
  }
    


public double totalBeforeTax() {
     double total =0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numPurchases; i++) {
            total += purchases[i].getQty()*purchases[i].getPrice();
        }
     return total;
}

//WORK ON THIS!
public double totalTax() {
    return totalBeforeTax();
}

public String toString() {
     StringBuilder info = new StringBuilder();
     //Append the Format the Table of Item
        info.append(String.format("%-15s","Item")).append("\n");
        info.append("---------------------------------------------------").append("\n");
        
        //Display Items inside the toString
        for (int i = 0; i < numPurchases; i++) {
            info.append(purchases[i]).append("\n");
        }
        
        //Append the Before Tax, Tax, Total, and Number of Items
        info.append("---------------------------------------------------").append("\n");
        info.append("Before Tax: ").append(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(totalBeforeTax())).append("\n");
        info.append("Tax: ").append(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(totalTax())).append("\n");
        info.append("Total: ").append(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(totalBeforeTax()+totalTax())).append("\n");
       //WORK ON THIS!
       info.append("Number of items: " + purchases[numPurchases]);
     
     return info.toString();
    }
 
}
```

Comment: What is your actual problem? Does the code you have posted not work? If not, in what way does it not work? Please clarify. Also, your implementation of `equals()` suggests that all animals of the same type are the same animal,  which seems incorrect.

Comment: @Bohemian sorry wrong question.. here the correct question I was asking about.